# Tile Engine in LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, sprite, lwjgl, tiles

I'm doing a rewrite of a game I've been working on with LWJGL(the original engine was in pure java) and I'm wanting to know the most effective way of rendering the map to the screen. I'm going to make a Tiled map and have a layer each for walkable tiles, collision tiles and stationary objects. All of which I'll be reading into the game by parsing an XML file.

My question is should I do it like this and read each tile into the game individually and store the values into a 2d array, assign them to sprites and render each sprite onto the screen in its respective location? Or would it be less taxing on the CPU/GPU to make these layers their own single picture file and render the layers rather than tiles? I assume the second one would be more of a pain in the ass, but is it worth it?

Comment: Modern GPUs can render tens of millions of triangles per second. The second way might be slightly faster, but it just won't matter when you're using only 0.01% of the capacity to start with.

Comment: Ohhh. Well I was reading somewhere earlier how some guy had around 700 sprites being rendered on screen and he was having significant lag because of it, but I guess he didn't specify what the resolution for those sprites was. However, I'll be using 16x16 or 32x32, so I think you're right.

Comment: He was probably rendering his sprites in a dumb way, like re-uploading them every frame.

Comment: How do I not do that?

Comment: Well, uploading a texture is calling `glTexImage2D` or similar functions. So, don't call those every frame? Or just don't worry about performance until you actually have a problem.

Comment: So you're saying that I should upload all of my textures upon starting the game and just render them when needed?

Comment: Yes. But that's how any texture tutorial will tell you to do it - you'd have to go out of your way to upload them every frame.

Comment: Yeah, that's kinda what I was thinking. I actually have one more question, I'm sorry. haha. How can I only render sprites that are actually on the screen at any given moment and ignore the rest?

Comment: 1. determine which sprites are on the screen. 2. render those ones.

Comment: Well I disagree, the second way will definitely be faster, especially if you are drawing each tile separately. This means say you have 500 tiles, on one layer. If you just draw the image of the map, you will make 1 call to your graphics card to render. However if you loop over 500 tiles, and then draw each one, its going to be making 500 calls. A way around this is to make a mesh from all of your tiles using a VBO then you are essentially only making one render call, but there is still more geometry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to combine the tiles together to form one big texture atlas. Assuming that you use 32x32 pixel tiles, a 2k texture can hold up to 4096 different tiles, potentially way more than enough for a game. The reason is that you can bind this texture once and do (almost) all rendering with it, avoiding the expensive texture switching operation. Do not use separate pictures for each tile. All textures and other rendering resources should uploaded up front, perferably at game load or level load.

As for the actual tiles and objects, you should build a vertex buffer which contains vertex attributes for all objects and upload it during level load too. This buffer will contain vertices positions, colors, texture coordinates... everything you need for drawing the tiles, and it can be splited into multiple buffer if one is not enough. For every frame, you use camera coordinates to find out which tiles are visible and which tiles are not, then issue a draw call with starting index of the first visible tile, and the count of visible tiles. Simple AABB check is pretty good here. Of course, in order to achieve this, your vertex buffer must be laid out in such a way that it only goes in one direction, e.g. left to right and top to bottom.

Alternatively, you can go more for more aggresive vertex count trimming at the cost of a few more draw calls: Splitting the world into chunks such that each chunk is big enough to cover the whole screen. Create vertex buffer for each chunk as described above. Then do the same camera check to find out which chunk is visible and draw them. In this case, you have at least 1 chunk visible and at most 4 chunks visible at any given time, which means 1 to 4 draw calls. This approach is a bit more advantagous than the previous because instead of having to loop over every single tile, you can loop over the chunks which means a lot less checks needed.

If done correctly, you probably won't need more than a handful of draw calls to render the world and be still able to draw a huge number of tiles. Apparently, this this only meant for static objects, you will need to draw dynamic objects differently. Keep it in mind that draw calls can context switching are expensive and should be avoided when possible.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am pretty new to OpenGL, so I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around all of this stuff. I'm also not finding resources that actually show what these openGL objects do and how to use them. Can you point me to a resource that explains those topics you mentioned?

Comment: This is a good one to get started with openGL http://learnopengl.com/. It uses C++ but everything should be the same with java. Regarding optimization, it is a pretty broad and complicated topic, so let's not worry too much for now.

Comment: It's all good; I'm currently making a 2D game, so I really doubt rendering is going to need too much optimization to work. Thanks man!